# Image gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a database column with number (0 or 1) if is 0 in my gridview column I don't want to show anything if is 1 instead I wanna show an Image.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgCtrl" runat="server" ToolTip="User counted" Visible='<%# (int.Parse(Eval("Pertico").ToString()) == 1 ? "/Images/Stack/it" : "") %>' />
```

But as I thought it's good for showing two different Images on 2 different values.

Is there some way to achieve this in my template field? Like putting a static image in it:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgCtrlEmergency" ToolTip="User counted" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/Stack/it" />
```

and from my codebehind check if it is 0 or 1?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="390" Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("yourColumn")) == 1 ? "true" : "false" %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this easily using RowDataBound :

```
Private Sub gvList_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvList.RowDataBound
    Dim myImageFeild As WebControls.Image = e.Row.FindControl("imgCtrl")
    myImageFeild.Visible = IIf(e.Row.DataItem("MyColumnShowImage") = 1, True, False)
End Sub
```

And :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgCtrl" runat="server" ToolTip="User counted" />
```

Good luck !